# FileUploadSupport with ScalatraFilter?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, scalatra

I'm in the midst of adding file upload support to my Scalatra application, and I followed the [official docs](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.scalatra.org/guides/formats/upload.html&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNGTrhgdYQ3Z3EtCjYYrtGP1uNoSmA), but the approach doesn't seem to work for ScalatraFilters--only ScalatraServlets.

For example, if I just [generate a new Scalatra project](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.scalatra.org/2.2/getting-started/first-project.html&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNFLO8BbpOhrK9-JCJ7E_P5zyU8t0Q), then extend the ScalatraServlet with FileUploadSupport (with configureMultipartHandling beneath as noted, or  in the web.xml file), everything works fine, but if I switch that ScalatraServlet to a ScalatraFilter, there doesn't seem to be any support--despite the codebase noting that "FileUploadSupport can be mixed into a [[org.scalatra.ScalatraFilter]] or [[org.scalatra.ScalatraServlet]]".

Does anyone have advice as to how I can include FileUploadSupport when I'm working with a ScalatraFilter rather than a ScalatraServlet? Maybe I'm just missing something obvious, here.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what "doesn't seem to be any support" means from your question, but in a quick experiment changing the extending class from a `ScalatraServlet` to a `ScalatraFilter`, I encountered different route handling.

My experiments show that `FileUploadSupport` is supported for a `ScalatraFilter`, however I noticed that the same path didn't work when it was converted to a filter.  Here are some results:

```
ScalatraBootstrap route | router get() | worked for
------------------------------------------------------
"/upload/*"             | "/"          | servlet
"/"                     | "/upload"    | filter ( like their FilterExample setup )
"/upload"               | "/upload"    | filter
```

In each case, the "worked for" means that I was able to see the example form listed on the upload documentation page.  Clicking on the browse button opened an finder window from an FF browser.  I have scalatra 2.10-2.2.2 if that makes a difference.  I used the same route for the post() function in my "upload router" and was able to output some info from the upload in each case.